# "Never" vs. "never ever"

Tags: meaning, differences, negation

Example:

> - I **never** use this cup.
> - I **never ever** use this cup.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: _Ever_ means _at any time_ and it's a Negative Polarity Item, in the scope of the negative trigger _Never_. Roughly, that means that since _Never at any time_ is grammatical, so is _Never ever_.

Comment: What John said...and since **"never"** has a very specific meaning, **"never ever"** only adds a degree of emphasis.

Comment: I'm with Kristina and John. Saying "never ever" only adds emphasis. It's like saying "I really, really like it" instead of "I really like it".

Comment: Two words one cup.

Comment: Never ever is emphatic, but it is also not formal register. That is, it would not be used in  formal writing or speech. It's colloquial register.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is, as Kristina Lopez pointed out, a matter of "degree of emphasis."  If you **really** wanted to emphasize your utter unwillingness to use a particular cup, you could add a comma after the word *never*, so as to slow the reader down and make him or her pause for effect.

That technique would also work well with the spoken word, if you were to raise slightly the volume of your voice on the word *ever*:

> I never, **ever** use this cup.

There can then be no doubt in the reader's or listener's mind that you are loath to use that cup!  (I'd feel the same way if the cup was used, for example, to scoop up poopy kitty litter!  Yuck!)

Comment: Good example of when to nev-ah, ev-ah...use that cup! :-)

Comment: Perhaps there's a whiff of childishness with 'never ever'. Churchill, if I remember correctly, once addressed a school at speech day: 'Never...never... _never_ ...never... **never** give up!'